# Why recycle posts for people who aren't interested?

Tags: discussion

This [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49485/mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly) reappeared on dba.stackexchange a few minutes ago (01:20 UTC), but the person who asked the original question hasn't visited the site for almost 9 months.

Why should questions by people who don't bother to visit regularly be recycled? I actually like the idea of recycling - it gives posters whose posts have fallen off the radar a second crack of the whip. However, this "bonus" should, I feel, only be given to those who make the effort to drop in from time to time. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason it was bumped is that it was modified by the community user:

> [image]

You are right that it was to get attention for an unanswered post. The algorithm is different per site, but it doesn't take the user's presence into account - likely for reasons already discussed: why does it matter if that user didn't stick around? If it was a good question, or at least not a bad question (as shown by the non-negative score), doesn't it still deserve an answer, for the benefit of the site and the community, if not for the original user? Also, remember that the asker may not *seem* to still be around, but he/she actually could be - they could be lurking, or using a different account (this is certainly common when someone has had a question migrated here).

I don't think we really have any control over this on our site, and you'd have to make a pretty compelling argument that bumping this post was somehow bad in order to make any changes that would make us special:

> The Community user will bump non-negatively scored questions that have at least one answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that. The number of unanswered questions bumped per hour depends on the site: 4 per hour on Stack Overflow, 1 per hour on Meta, and 2 per hour on Super User and Server Fault. The default for a new site is 1 per hour.

You can get more background [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230570/165455) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-my-question-to-be-bumped).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe as a variation, your question needs to be upvoted (to ensure it's a worthwhile question)? Or combine the two - in order for a community bump, the question needs to be upvoted and you have to have been active within the past month?

Comment: Good point - some questions are of interest no matter who asks them. I'll give a +1 to a combination of either user activity and/or upvotes (maybe 2?).

Comment: bear in mind it's the answers that need upvotes to not get re-bumped